# Form Submission in Laravel 8 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, laravel, form-submit

```
<a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"  style="display:none">
@csrf
</form>
```

I am trying to submit the form above but keeps returning this error
`(index):36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'submit')`

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here please?

Comment: We probably need to see the controller logic.

Answer (score -1):

I found out what was wrong.  The problem was that I had a form within another form.  Thanks guys anyway.

Comment: This is unlikely to help future readers. It would be better to just delete the question in this case.